# What graphic card driver should I install?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, amd-graphics

I use Ubuntu 22.04 and my laptop has Intel 530 and GeForce 960M graphic cards I think. Recently because of either upgrading my graphic driver or OS kernel, I have an issue with my graphic card. I wanted to make sure what driver should I install?

When I run  `apt search nvidia-driver` it shows up a long list as below. It seems some of them are free and some are not? Also there are headless, server, Xorg, etc versions.

What is the best free graphic driver I can install on my Ubuntu 22.04?

```
nvidia-384/jammy-updates,jammy-security 390.157-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-390

nvidia-384-dev/jammy-updates,jammy-security 390.157-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-390

nvidia-driver-390/jammy-updates,jammy-security 390.157-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64
  NVIDIA driver metapackage

nvidia-driver-418/jammy 430.50-0ubuntu3 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-430

nvidia-driver-418-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 418.226.00-0ubuntu5~0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA Server Driver metapackage

nvidia-driver-430/jammy 440.100-0ubuntu1 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-440

nvidia-driver-435/jammy 455.45.01-0ubuntu1 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-455

nvidia-driver-440/jammy 450.119.03-0ubuntu1 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-450

nvidia-driver-440-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 450.248.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-450-server

nvidia-driver-450/jammy 460.91.03-0ubuntu1 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-460

nvidia-driver-450-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 450.248.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA Server Driver metapackage

nvidia-driver-455/jammy 460.91.03-0ubuntu1 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-460

nvidia-driver-460/jammy-updates,jammy-security 470.199.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-470

nvidia-driver-460-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 470.199.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-470-server

nvidia-driver-465/jammy-updates,jammy-security 470.199.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-470

nvidia-driver-470/jammy-updates,jammy-security 470.199.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA driver metapackage

nvidia-driver-470-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 470.199.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA Server Driver metapackage

nvidia-driver-495/jammy-updates,jammy-security 510.108.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-510

nvidia-driver-510/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-525

nvidia-driver-510-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-515-server

nvidia-driver-515/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-525

nvidia-driver-515-open/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-525

nvidia-driver-515-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-525-server

nvidia-driver-520/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-525

nvidia-driver-520-open/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-525

nvidia-driver-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA driver metapackage

nvidia-driver-525-open/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA driver (open kernel) metapackage

nvidia-driver-525-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA Server Driver metapackage

nvidia-driver-530/jammy-updates,jammy-security 535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-535

nvidia-driver-530-open/jammy-updates,jammy-security 535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-535-open

nvidia-driver-535/jammy-updates,jammy-security 535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA driver metapackage

nvidia-driver-535-open/jammy-updates,jammy-security 535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA driver (open kernel) metapackage

nvidia-driver-535-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA Server Driver metapackage

nvidia-driver-535-server-open/jammy-updates,jammy-security 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA driver (open kernel) metapackage

nvidia-headless-390/jammy-updates,jammy-security 390.157-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage

nvidia-headless-418-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 418.226.00-0ubuntu5~0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage

nvidia-headless-450-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 450.248.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage

nvidia-headless-470/jammy-updates,jammy-security 470.199.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage

nvidia-headless-470-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 470.199.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage

nvidia-headless-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage

nvidia-headless-525-open/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage (open kernel module)

nvidia-headless-525-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage

nvidia-headless-535/jammy-updates,jammy-security 535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage

nvidia-headless-535-open/jammy-updates,jammy-security 535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage (open kernel module)

nvidia-headless-535-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage

nvidia-headless-535-server-open/jammy-updates,jammy-security 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage (open kernel module)

nvidia-headless-no-dkms-390/jammy-updates,jammy-security 390.157-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage - no DKMS

nvidia-headless-no-dkms-418-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 418.226.00-0ubuntu5~0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage - no DKMS

nvidia-headless-no-dkms-450-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 450.248.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage - no DKMS

nvidia-headless-no-dkms-470/jammy-updates,jammy-security 470.199.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage - no DKMS

nvidia-headless-no-dkms-470-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 470.199.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage - no DKMS

nvidia-headless-no-dkms-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage - no DKMS

nvidia-headless-no-dkms-525-open/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage - no DKMS (open kernel module)

nvidia-headless-no-dkms-525-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage - no DKMS

nvidia-headless-no-dkms-535/jammy-updates,jammy-security 535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage - no DKMS

nvidia-headless-no-dkms-535-open/jammy-updates,jammy-security 535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage - no DKMS (open kernel module)

nvidia-headless-no-dkms-535-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage - no DKMS

nvidia-headless-no-dkms-535-server-open/jammy-updates,jammy-security 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA headless metapackage - no DKMS (open kernel module)

xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390/jammy-updates,jammy-security 390.157-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64
  NVIDIA binary Xorg driver

xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-418-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 418.226.00-0ubuntu5~0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA binary Xorg driver

xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 450.248.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA binary Xorg driver

xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470/jammy-updates,jammy-security 470.199.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA binary Xorg driver

xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 470.199.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA binary Xorg driver

xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA binary Xorg driver

xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-525-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA binary Xorg driver

xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-535/jammy-updates,jammy-security 535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA binary Xorg driver

xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-535-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
  NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```